# An example of a function which is not piecewise continuous, but has Fourier series

Tags: fourier-series

Would you Please give an example of a function which is not piecewise continuous, but has Fourier series?

It means that the coefficient in the Euler-Fourier formulas can be computed. In fact, the definite integrals exist.

Comment: If you are only requiring that the coefficients make sense, then you can take any $f \in L^2$, even wildly discontinuous functions. It is when you require more convergence than just convergence in $L^2$, such as convergence almost everywhere, that you need to require regularity.

Comment: Yes, It is piecewise continuous.

Comment: Ian No, I just want a function as I stated in my question.

Comment: The characteristic function, Do the difinite integrals (Riemann) exist? I don,t think so.

Comment: They exist in the sense of Lebesgue integration. Coming up with a Riemann integrable example is more difficult, since a Riemann integrable function is continuous almost everywhere. (This is called Lebesgue's criterion for Riemann integrability.) You might consider a Riemann integrable function whose set of discontinuities is a Cantor set of measure zero. This just amounts to building en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function with the usual Cantor set replacing the "fat" (positive measure) Smith-Volterra-Cantor set.

Comment: You might also consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function , which is discontinuous at every rational number and is Riemann integrable (again by Lebesgue's criterion).

Comment: (Of course, Thomae's function is *also* 0 almost everywhere, so its Fourier series converges to the zero function, just like the characteristic function of the rationals does.)

Comment: Thanks, Ian, for following up here and teasing out the question that OP actually wanted answered. If OP had mentioned Riemann integration, I might have written a more elaborate answer. :)

Comment: Thank you John and Ian for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the characteristic function $c$ of the rationals; it's 1 at every rational, 0 at every irrational. Its FT is the constant function 0. Because $c$ is equal, almost everywhere, to the constant function $0$, they have the same FT.